# Expo React Native openDrawer() not working on IOS

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo

Here is my component. The drawer works well on Android but it does nothing on IOS.

```
...
export default function Dashboard({navigation}:{navigation: any}) {
    const [usr_id, setUsrId] = useState("");
    const [full_name, setFullName] = useState("")
    
    const navigation_drawer = useNavigation<DrawerNavigationProp<ParamListBase>>()

    useEffect(() => {
        const isLoggedIn = async () => {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("usrId");
            if (value == null) navigation.navigate('Home'); 
            else {
                setUsrId(value);
                const fullName = await AsyncStorage.getItem("fullName");
                if (fullName == null) setFullName("No Name")
                else {
                    setFullName(fullName);
                }
            }
        }
        isLoggedIn();
    },[])

    return (
        
        <View>
            <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5'}}>
                <LinearGradient
                    // Background Linear Gradient
                    colors={['#F75A00', '#FF9D65']}
                    style={styles.header}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation_drawer.openDrawer()} style={styles.hamburgerIconWrapper}> //NOT WORKING ON IOS
                    <Icon name="menu" size={32}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
...
```

Some solutions advised to change

```
navigation_drawer.openDrawer()
```

to

```
navigation_drawer.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer()
```

But it doesnt seem to help or trigger anything.

EDIT:
I am sharing the versions used in the project:
package.json:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.12",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.5.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.71.1",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

More routing info:
App.tsx:

```
...
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>()
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();


function Root() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="ראשי" component={Dashboard} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="היסטוריית קריאות" component={History} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="התנתק" component={Home} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <NavigationContainer >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Stack.Navigator screenOptions= {{headerShown:false}}>
            <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown:false}} name="Root" component={Root} /> 
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Stack.Screen name="History" component={History} />
            {/* <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} /> */}
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </View>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}
```

More info will be added upon request.
Thank you very much in advance.
Adding more words because SO asks to...

Comment: please share your minimum navigation route n what version you use

Comment: @bagi2info.com
Post edited.
What is "minimun navigation route"?

Comment: your navigation route code stack drawer etc

Comment: I test it, it was working fine on Iphone 11 pro, testing code https://snack.expo.dev/@rudiahmad/test?platform=web

Comment: @bagi2info.com 
Why doesn`t it work on my physical device?

Comment: I create with the simple code, it might be your code or library cause it, also I didnt compile it on device, test it on expo, my question why you need stack if drawer have same menu?

Comment: @bagi2info.com
I thought the drawer creates the menu

Comment: Yes drawer create menu but it have same page with the stack, how about just use the drawer only no need stack anymore?